# Removing buttons in WebView2 PDF preview

Tags: c#, pdf, button, toolbar, webview2

I was wondering if a i can remove the buttons in the red box .. check the link below

[Form  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOhQB.png) : i can't add images yet

I want to disable the "save" and "print" function

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PdfViewer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Task App { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeWebView();
        }

        private void InitializeWebView()
        {
            App = webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await App;
            webView21.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
            if (webView21 != null && webView21.CoreWebView2 != null)
            {
                webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate(@"C:\sample.pdf");
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webView21.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
            if (webView21 != null && webView21.CoreWebView2 != null)
            {
                webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate(addressBar.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve? Note that users can still right-click or choose a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @PoulBak i can disable the right click.. i just want to stop the users from accessing the server local storage by opening the explorer

Answer (score 3):

We have a prerelease API to hide buttons in the PDF view. You can see it in the [CoreWebView2Settings.HiddenPdfToolbarItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.hiddenpdftoolbaritems?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1158-prerelease) documentation.

```cs
this.webview2.CoreWebView2.Settings.HiddenPdfToolbarItems = 
    CoreWebView2PdfToolbarItems.Save | 
    CoreWebView2PdfToolbarItems.SaveAs | 
    CoreWebView2PdfToolbarItems.Print;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I tried adding Fullscreen and MoreSettings and it does not work. Is there some limit to it?